# java.lang.ClassCastException when casting Object-result of java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke

Tags: java, eclipse, reflection, invoke, classcastexception

I load dynamically an external class from my eclipse rcp application with urlClassLoader. The invoke()-method returns an Object of self-defined Type.

```
ClassLoader oldClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();  
URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance( url);  
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(cl);  
String className ="myClass";
Class<?> c = cl.loadClass(className);
Object inst =c.newInstance();
Method run =c.getMethod("run", new Class[0]);
Object rdsObject =run.invoke(inst, new Object[]{});
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader( oldClassLoader );
rts.data.RTSDataSet rds =(rts.data.RTSDataSet) rdsObject;
```

When I'm trying to cast this Object, I get the java.lang.ClassCastException : rts.data.RTSDataSet cannot be cast to rts.data.RTSDataSet. It seems to me, that the reason is that I have here different ClassLoader. My Question is : how should I set the ClassLoader properly?
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the two-argument form of `URLClassLoader.newInstance` to set the parent class loader to be that of the calling code.

```
 URLClassLoader loaders = URLClassLoader.newInstance(path, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

Comment: Wouldn't this have worked `URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(url, oldClassLoader);`?

Comment: The Elite Gentleman Depends what that `oldClassLoader` was... You almost never want to rely upon `Thread.getContextClassLoader`.